# Alternative to PowerShell Register-ObjectEvent (which causes some problems with the threading)

Tags: .net, powershell, event-handling

The problem is that `Register-ObjectEvent` in Powershell causes some problems with the threading problems and possible crashes (as also mentioned on WinSCP .NET assembly homepage - https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell).

The same in my script, one file upload works, but the 2nd is not working, it is cancelled within the action ( it hangs according to logs after trying to upload).

This problem is only present in PowerShell 2.0, after that (3.0+) it is working really good.

Is there any solution to this problem or maybe another opportunity to `Register-ObjectEvent`?

Thanks for your help!

Answer (score 0):

As the [WinSCP documentation for event handlers](https://winscp.net/eng/docs/library_powershell#event_handlers), that you reference yourself, says:

> Associate the event handling function using `.add_Event` "methods" where `Event` is a name of the event.
>
> ```
> # Event handling function
> function FileTransferred
> {
>     param($e)
>
>     if ($e.Error -eq $Null)
>     {
>         Write-Host "Transfer of $($e.FileName) succeeded"
>     }
>     else
>     {
>         Write-Host "Transfer of $($e.FileName) failed: $($e.Error)"
>     }
> }
>
> ...
>
> # Subscribe to the event
> $session.add_FileTransferred( { FileTransferred($_) } )
> ```